# Word to describe flavor of anise, licorice, and fennel?

Tags: food

Is there a word to describe the flavor common to anise, licorice, and fennel? It tastes kind of sweet, but has a "bite".

Edit: here it is described as "licoricelike": http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/aniseed

Comment: Yes, the flavor is anise.

Comment: I'd call it [anethole](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anethole).

Comment: I take that back.  The flavor is licorice.  (I see more references to "licorice flavor" than I do to "anise flavor".)

Comment: Could there be some relation to liqueur, because of the English spelling? Was this used widely as a flavor compound for liqueurs? Buried underneath the sweetness (just as in the confectionery).

Comment: FYI--Anethole is the chemical compound, not the taste or aroma. Licorice tends toward bitter, whereas anise is more sweet and spicy. They have similar aromas. The aromas' contributions to taste are likely driving the perceived taste similarity.

Answer (score 8):

Kenneth T. Farrell describes the aroma and flavor of fennel seed in his book *[Spices, Condiments and Seasonings](https://books.google.com/books?id=ehAFUhWV4QMC&pg=PA93&dq=anetholic&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CB0Q6AEwAGoVChMIn_73v6eGxgIVjC2MCh10kQD9#v=onepage&q=anetholic&f=false)*:

> The odor of the essential oil has been characterized as being
> aromatic, pleasantly fresh, warm, spicy, aniselike, slightly
> camphoraceous, changing to a heavier camphoraceous note when dried
> out, leaving an anetholic back note. The flavor has also been
> described as being *[warm](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/warm)*, *[spicy](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/spicy)*, *[aniselike](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/anise)*,
> *[aromatic](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/aromatic)*, *[green](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/green)*, *[herbaceous](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/herbaceous)*, initially bitter, then sweet, with a fresh, slightly bitter, aftertaste.
>
> ***Emphasis** added*

The term *[piquant](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/piquant)* captures the commonality of those specific descriptions:

> adjective
>
> 1 Having a pleasantly sharp taste or appetizing flavour:
>
> <sub>ODO</sub>

*Some people enjoy the **piquant** flavor of anise, while others do not.*

The term *[aromatic](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/aromatic)* seems to evoke connotations of the bittersweet aroma, which has great impact on the bittersweet flavor:

> adjective
>
> 1 Having a pleasant and distinctive smell:
>
> <sub>ODO</sub>

Comment: I'd use *piquant* for spicier flavors like salsa or capers.  I think *aromatic* hits closer to home...IMO. :-)

Comment: I think piquant is not it; I reserve it for anything pickled, some strongly fermented cheeses, sour cream such as Kefir; foods of this kind. Capers is a match in this respect, and certainly some spicy sauces - likely coming from the pickled ingredients. To me, piquant requires a salivating hit of sour.

Answer (score 1):

*[Bittersweet](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/bittersweet)*:

> adjective
>
> 1 (Of food or drink) sweet with a bitter aftertaste:
>
> *ODO*